# Type restriction for class members in case/when

Tags: crystal-lang

Let's say I have following class `Message` representing a message in a chat.

```
class Message
    JSON.mapping({
        message_id: {type: Int32},
        text:       {type: String, nilable: true},
        photo:      {type: Photo, nilable: true},
        sticker:    {type: Sticker, nilable: true},
    })

    MESSAGE_TYPES = %w( text photo sticker )

    {% for type in MESSAGE_TYPES %}
        def {{ type.id }}?
        ! {{ type.id }}.nil?
        end
    {% end %}
end
```

Every message can be either text, or photo, or sticker. But only one of those. For instance, if message is a text, then `photo` and `sticker` properties are nil, but `text` is not nil. If message is a sticker, only `sticker` is not nil. And so on. Real class has much more direct types and inferred types.

Upon receiving this message, I want to process it in a way specific for particular type. Something like:

```
case message
when .text?
    p message.text
when .photo?
    p message.photo.file_id
when .sticker?
    p message.sticker.file_id
end
```

Of course, it won't work, because in each `when` clause corresponding properties are nilable and `undefined method 'file_id' for Nil`.

Is there any way to restrict variable type in each case making sure that is `message.sticker?` then `message.sticker` is not nil and `file_id` exists?

Maybe I'm completely wrong in very approaching the problem and there better and cleaner ways to code this?

Answer (score 2):

```
require "json"

class Photo
  JSON.mapping(url: String)
end

struct Message
  JSON.mapping(id: Int32, message: String|Photo)
end

p Message.from_json(%({"id": 5, "message": {"url": "http://example.org/"}}))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put all payload objects in one instance variable with a union type as Oleh Prypin suggested.
Another option, if you want to keep the current data layout, you could have the methods return the respective Type or `nil` and assign its value to a variable:

```
if text = message.text?
  p text
if photo = message.photo?
  p photo.file_id
if sticker = message.sticker?
  p sticker.file_id
end
```

Comment: That's really good idea. But I'm still confused, can I declare a new type inheriting only part of the parent class JSON mappings, or I have to declare a full list of mapping in each subtype?

Comment: There's only the one JSON mapping in the Message class like in your example.